# wp7 Error in Binding Data of ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to use a collection of checkboxes (created in runtime) within a ListBox. The XAML I am writing is

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding}" Name="cuisineList">
               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid Height="45" Name="grid1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="230*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="230*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding content}" Name="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding content}" Name="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and the code is

```
public ObservableCollection<Cuisine> Items = new ObservableCollection<Cuisine>();
    public Search()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Cuisine());
        }
        cuisineList.DataContext = Items;
    }
```

But when I run my app, I don't see any check box. Please point out the mistake and help me rectify it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the itemsource of the listbox as follows

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="cuisineList">
```

```
                    <Grid Height="45" Name="grid1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="230*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="230*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding content}" Name="Check1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding content}" Name="Check2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Also is there any restriction to write Items in *.xaml.cs file ??

If not write in a view model say PageViewModel.cs file

then Set Viewmodel class object as page.xaml data context. 
(

> this.DataContext = new PageViewModel();

Write the this statement in the constructor of Page.xaml.cs file)

Also verify that the **Cuisine** has public property **Content**

Comment: can't I have the `NAME` property of the CheckBox dynamic as well?

Comment: No, you can not use , it gives a "Null Reference Exception" as Invalid Pointer. while creation.

Answer (score -1):

you need to set the items source on the listbox.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="cuisineList">
```

Comment: getting a series of runtime errors -
''UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.dll'